# What is the best way to implement LinkedIn Authentication in MVC6 ASP.NET5 web app

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, linkedin-api

There is no LinkedIn-specific library from Microsoft like Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook. The third party libraries I tried are designed for ASP.NET4.5.

Answer (score 1):

I also waiting for middleware for LinkedIn authentication from aspnet team, but look like they have no plans to create it - read [LinkedIn Authentication](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/777) and [Will we have a Authentication.LinkedIn](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/397).

> @Tratcher wrote:
>
> No, but there's a comunity implementation available here: [aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers)

You can try this one above and please let me know if it's working well, please.

Also You can create middleware yourself based on generic OAuth middleware...

Check [aspnet/Security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security) repo on GitHub, and read [LinkedIn Authenticating with OAuth 2.0](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) article.

Comment: It gives me all kinds of compilation errors in my own code, which worked fine before installation. E.g. now the project can't find ILogger

Answer (score 1):

As Lukasz pointed out, you can use the LinkedIn provider in the https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers project. I wrote that provider and it is just a thin layer on top of the built-in generic OAuth2 provider.

It you want to use the generic OAuth2 provider directly, you can also look at this blog post which takes you step-by-step through the entire process:

https://auth0.com/blog/2016/06/13/authenticating-a-user-with-linkedin-in-aspnet-core/